# KX Developer:How to use show in kx developer

Tags: ide, report, kdb

When I use kx developer, I found that when using show, an error will be reported, such as:

```
show "abc"
```

The developer will report an error,[image: error message]
By the way, my error message is not displayed completely, can you help me solve it, thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Question cross posted here: https://community.kx.com/t5/KX-Solutions/KX-Developer-show-doesn-t-work/m-p/14012#M533

Are you using Windows 11? It's not on the officially supported list

Comment: Yes, I am using windows11.That is, there is no way to solve this problem？